# How to propagate keystrokes to every frame in an HTML page?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

My company doesn't allow me to show the code so I will describe it the best I can.

I have an HTML page containing 4 frames.

- One on top containing the title and some other and the user's name
- One one the bottom containing the version and other pieces of information
- One on the left containing the menu
- The last one is on the right and contains the content of the website.

Each frame contains an .aspx page. The page of the left frame doesn't change, and the one on the write is almost always changing. The 2 others don't matter.

I've been asked to add shortcuts leading to differents places. Those shorcuts will involve F keys. For instance, F1 will open the PDF help file in a new tab, F2 will lead to a certain page, etc...

I am using IE8 and I can't update it. And I know that some F keys are already used by it but I found a way to disable the functions called by them so that I can use them for my own shortcuts.

I tried to add the shortcuts in Javascript with a function which checks if a F key is pressed and released. I have successfully added this function in my left frame which always contains the same .aspx page, but as soon as I click on the right frame, it seems that I lose the focus on the other one and the shortcut doesn't work anymore. My problem is that in the right frame, about a hundred different .aspx can be called, so I can't add the Javascript function in each one. Moreover, I do not have access to the HTML page containing the frames, so I can not add the code here neither.

The best for me would be to be able to have the shorcut function in my left frame and that it is called even if the focus is on my right panel.

Do you know if a such thing is possible ? Or do you have any idea of any other way to solve this issue ?

Thanks.

(And forgive me for my bad grammar, english is not my native language)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need the functionality (ie JavaScript) repeated in every frame where you need it.

What you can do is create a base page and then inherit your ASPX pages from that, for instance:

```
public class PageWithShortcuts : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    // Add JavaScript-outputting functions and other shared functionality here
    private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterStartupScript("mycode", "<script>...</script>");
    }
}
```

Your pages then all inherit from this:

```
public class CheckoutPage : PageWithShortcuts
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the RegisterStartupScript method. All my .aspx pages actually inherit from an already existing page, so this solves my problem.